# Remove Duplicates From For Loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I remove the duplicate items from my for loop?

I assume via a computed function or is there something I can simply add to the loop below to only output the duplicates from my data.

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index" class="form-check">
    <div v-for="(cat, index) in item.category_data" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="cat_data" :id="index" :value="index">
        <label class="form-check-label">{{ cat }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code Pen with duplicates**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxNORW?editors=1010

Thanks

Comment: If you do not want to modify the underlying data via a computed property you could use a filter. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're many ways to achieve "Remove Duplicates From For Loop"

just make a example:

```
remove_category_duplicates: function () {
    // Get all categories and remove duplicates
    let data = {}
    this.info.forEach(i=>{
        Object.assign(data,i.category_data)
    })
    return data;
 }
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/timtnlee/pen/ePgKQO?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do too much in your markup. Keep any data processing as small as possible in markup.

I'd therefore advise that you use a filter to return an array with the duplicates removed.

### Markup

```
 <div v-for="(filteredArray(arr), index) in info" :key="index" class="form-check">
   ...
</div>
```

### Script

Add the filtered property to your vue.js instance.

```
filters: {
  filteredArray: function (array) {
    let data = {}
    this.info.forEach(i=>{
      Object.assign(data,i.category_data)
     })
    return data;
  }
}
```